# The closure of the union of any family of regular closed sets is also regular closed set

Tags: general-topology

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called regular closed provided $%
A=cl_{X}\left( int_{X}\left( A\right) \right) $.

If $\left( A_{i}\right) _{i}$ is a family of regular closed sets, then $%
cl_{X}\left( \cup _{i}A_{i}\right) $ is regular closed. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a family $(A_i)$ of regular closed sets.

Because $A_i \subset cl(A_i)$, then taking the interior then the closure, you get $cl(int(A_i)) \subset cl(int(cl(A_i)))$. But by hypothesis, $cl(int(A_i)) = A_i$, so you get $A_i \subset cl(int(cl(A_i)))$. In particular, you have then $A_i \subset cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i)))$, and so $\cup_i A_i \subset cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i)))$. But because $cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i)))$ is closed, you deduce that $cl(\cup_i A_i) \subset cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i)))$. This is the first inclusion.

Conversely, notice that $int(cl(\cup_i A_i)) \subset cl(\cup_i A_i)$.Because $cl(\cup_i A_i)$ is closed, you deduce that $cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i))) \subset cl(\cup_i A_i)$. This is the second inclusion (which is always true).

Hence we have proved that $cl(int(cl(\cup_i A_i))) = cl(\cup_i A_i)$, i.e. that $cl(\cup_i A_i)$ is regular closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more readable answer. The key point is to notice that a subset $A\subset X$ is regularly closed if and only if it is the closure of some open set $U$. That is, if $A=cl(U)$, then necessarily $A=cl(int(A))$.

So take a family of regularly closed sets $\{A_i\subseteq X\}_\mathcal{I}$ and for each $i\in\mathcal{I}$ let $U_i\subseteq X$ be an open set with $A_i=cl(U_i)$. Then $A_i\subseteq cl\left(\bigcup U_i\right)$ and $U_i\subseteq A_i$ for each $i$. Thus

$$\bigcup A_i\subseteq cl\left(\bigcup U_i\right)\subseteq cl\left(\bigcup A_i\right).$$

By definition of the closure operator, the right-hand inclusion must be an equality. i.e.
$$cl\left(\bigcup U_i\right)= cl\left(\bigcup A_i\right)$$
which is the statement that $ cl\left(\bigcup A_i\right)$ is regularly closed, since $\bigcup U_i$ is open.

Comment: In line 5, $A_{i}\subseteq \cup U_{i}$ must be $A_{i}\subseteq cl\left( \cup
U_{i}\right) $, isn't it?

Comment: Mehmet, yes, that's what it should be, thanks for noticing.